# Testing the update / new release of an existing android app

Tags: android

If before I make any changes to an existing app, I install the app on one of the AVDs (by running the app on it) and then I make some code changes and run that new version of the app on the same AVD: does that simulate the update process that users of my app will have when they download the update of my app to their device using Google Play?

Comment: so will the final products of the two apps be the same including the existing DB data, etc?

Comment: Database data is questionable. If you don't change the version, then no data should be cleared, other than that, it's just installing an apk file over another, yes

Comment: @cricket_007: what version are you referring to?

Comment: Database version. The parameter to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, which I assume is what you mean by "existing DB data"